# MySQL Inconsistencies in index usage on the same query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table of over 9 million rows. I have a SELECT query that I'm using an index for. Here is the query:

```
SELECT `username`,`id`
FROM `04c1Tg0M`
WHERE `id` > 9259466
AND `tried` = 0
LIMIT 1;
```

That query executes very fast (0.00 sec). Here is the explain for that query:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | 04c1Tg0M | range | PRIMARY,triedex | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 10822 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Now here is the same query except that I'm going to change the id to 6259466:

```
SELECT `username`,`id`
FROM `04c1Tg0M`
WHERE `id` > 5986551
AND `tried` = 0
LIMIT 1;
```

That query took 4.78 seconds to complete. This is the problem. Here is the explain for that query:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | 04c1Tg0M | ref  | PRIMARY,triedex | triedex | 2       | const | 9275107 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

What is happening here and how can I fix it? Here are my indexes:

```
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| 04c1Tg0M |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     9275093 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | pdex     |            1 | username    | A         |     9275093 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | pdex     |            2 | id          | A         |     9275093 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | pdex     |            3 | tried       | A         |     9275093 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | triedex  |            1 | tried       | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | triedex  |            2 | id          | A         |     9275093 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

And here is my table structure:

```
| 04c1Tg0M | CREATE TABLE `04c1Tg0M` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`tried` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `pdex` (`username`,`id`,`tried`),
KEY `triedex` (`tried`,`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9275108 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Did you run those queries one immediately after the other?

Comment: within a few seconds of each other

Comment: Have you realized that you are examining 3M rows more (supousing the ids are correlative) than in the first query? You only get one row in the result but you are examining a lot of rows more.

Comment: @Ander2 that is likely a result of it not using the index.  NO index = must check more records before it finds the right one.  It is called a full-table scan.

Comment: Have you tried giving an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html) e.g. ``FROM `04c1Tg0M` FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)``?

Comment: forcing the index worked :) thank you

Comment: @eggyal: that raises the question, why is it not using the primary index anyway?

Comment: @xendi, is this table frequently updated? You may need to run an `OPTIMIZE` to bring the index up to date; BE CAREFUL: this locks that table until it completes.

Comment: @Dancrumb: I was rather hoping it might be obvious why the optimiser didn't choose that index when one forced it... as you say, the indexes may need to be `OPTIMIZE`d.  See http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/

Comment: each iteration of my loop either sets the row's tried column to 1 or removes the row.

Comment: There are no more than 9275108 records in the table, so `id > 9259466` doesn't have to check many index values. When changed to `id > 5986551`, it would have to look at many more values (possibly most). Because of this, I suppose the optimizer believes that using the index on `tried` will be more limiting than using the index on `id`, so it uses that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first SQL returns 10822 rows, while the second one returns 9275107 rows!

The use of primary key "id" index in the second query isn't so useful because you have to do a full table scan anyway.

MySQL's cost-based optimizer thinks, in the case of the 2nd query, it's better off to use the index on 'tried'.

If you have to do a full table-scan, you're better off not using an index, as index constitutes additional disk reads.

You can use "use index" or "force index" in your query to hint to the optimizer whether to use an index.

Also update the statistics by analyzing your table periodically so the cost-based optimizer is working correctly.

Comment: forcing an index or index hinting will definitely do the work